# Can AppleScript/osascript be used to click menu extra menu items?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, applescript, osascript

I have an application installed that only appears in the menu bar (as a menu extra to the right).  I would like to click one of the items contained in its menu via osascript.  I've found the following code snippet:

```
osascript -e '
  tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
      tell (1st menu bar item of menu bar 1 whose value of attribute "AXDescription" is "keymando menu extra")
         perform action "AXPress" of menu item "Edit Config" of menu 1
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell
```

Sadly, it does not work.  I assume I have the name of menu extra correct: "Keymando menu extra".

Answer (score 2):

SystemUIServer only includes menu extras (the icons on the right side that can be rearranged) but not status menus (like the one Keymando uses).

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 where description is "clock")
        click
        click menu item "Open Date & Time Preferences…" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

In some applications `menu bar 2` is the status menu, but `tell application "System Events" to UI elements of process "Keymando"` returns an empty list.

Comment: Is there anyway to access those other status men items?

Comment: THANK YOU!  This just solved my HOURS long search on how to do this

Answer (score 1):

it may be in there, 
this will write a list in temp folder, that you can look through for a 'handle'.

```
`osascript -sso > /private/tmp/StatusBarItems <&- <<EOF
tell application "System Events"
    get properties of every  menu bar item of every menu bar  of process "SystemUIServer"
end tell
EOF`
```

or you can experiment with

```
   ` osascript -sso > /private/tmp/SU_reLoad <&- <<BUTTON
tell application "System Events"
    click  menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process "SystemUIServer"
end tell
BUTTON`
```

unfortunately the one I want isn't there... The 'exit full screen button' for a 'none scriptable' app...
john

Answer (score 1):

I was able to open Hangouts with

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome" to tell menu bar 2
    click (first menu bar item where help is "Google Hangouts")
end tell
```